# Freemarker Dynamically reference tag outside my fo:table-body

Tags: freemarker, xsl-fo

I can't show you the whole code, but the following are basically the steps I'm taking to generate dynamic code inside my fo-table-body tag.

At a stage inside `<fo:table-body>`, I want to be able to reference the block named "ref" and change the value inside out if. Is this possible ?

```
<#assign value="Hello World"/>
<fo:block name"ref">
      <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Value: </fo:inline>
      <fo:inline>${Value}</fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
    // All sorts of data inside the tags 
         <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell></fo:table-cell>
         </fo:table-row> 
   </fo:table-body>
```

Comment: Just a note, you cannot start a table with fo:table-body, you need fo:table to surround that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker templates continuously write to the output as they are executed, so if you have already printed a piece of output, then it's not in the hands of FreeMarker anymore. (It might be still sitting in some buffer behind the `Writer`, but FreeMarker is not aware of that.) What you can do though is generating the dependency part (`fo:table-body`) first, but capturing it instead of printing it, like `<#assign tableBody><fo:table-body...>...</fo:table-body></#assign>`, then generate the dependent part (`fo:block`) as usual, then print the captured part (`${tableBody}`, or `<#noescape>${tableBody}</#noescape>`, depending on what kind of auto-escaping you use).